# Proving that $\sup_{||x||\leq 1}||f(x)|| = \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||f(x)||$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

In one exercice my teacher asked us to prove the following:

> Let $E,F$ be two normed spaces and $f:E\to F$ be a continuous linear map between them. Then $$\sup_{||x||\leq 1}||f(x)|| = \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||f(x)||$$

My approach was the following:

Let $a =\sup_{||x||\leq 1}||f(x)|| $
and $b = \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||f(x)||$. It's obvious that $b\leq a$ and I was trying to use the fact that: $$\exists M>0:\forall x\in E, ||f(x)||\leq M||x||$$
to show that $b$ is an upper bound of $\{||f(x)||, ||x||\leq 1\}$ and hence $a\leq b$, but I wasn't able to do so.
How can this be done?

Comment: For $x \neq 0$, think of $\lVert x \rVert f\left(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}\right)$

Comment: this is a linear map in normed space so just normalize :$\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$